# правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Мира подняла глаза на молодого человека, его лицо было в тени, поэтому разобрать было сложно кто это, но суть же была не в этом. Когда ты слышишь в голосе незнакомца знакомые ноты приключения, ответить невозможно. 
-Я и сама справлюсь, но…и от помощи не откажусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мира подняла глаза на молодого человека: его лицо было в тени, поэтому разобрать было сложно, кто это, но суть же была не в этом. Когда ты слышишь в голосе незнакомца знакомые ноты приключения, ответить невозможно.

-Я и сама справлюсь, но…и от помощи не откажусь.

Двоеточие имеет пояснительную функцию (то, что она увидела, о чем потом подумала). Абзац находится внутри диалога, знаками препинания с ним не связан.

Comment: абзац был, но что-то не отобразился. Спасибо большое, Вера)